# asynchronous Cypher query for neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

lets say i have a select query in cypher

```
MATCH (n:PERSON) RETURN n
```

this query should give me 70billion result. But it cant since the result data is really big.

or an update query

```
MATCH (n :PERSON)
SET n.name = NULL RETURN n
```

i know the queries are ridiculous but in order to tell that i can work with really big data i gave the examples above.

So now i want something asynchronously works and shows me the process. Sometimes we makes some typos on queries or make mistakes which value we want and the query works for hours. Ok it can work but we want to see when the result come or the process.

i wrote cypher but i read some articles they say there is some other ways to access or change the data.

so what should i do.

Comment: What you mean by 'async' process? How it supposed to return data?

Comment: @FylmTM especially update process it can say i updated %50 of data for example

Answer (score 0):

How about to write some kind of batch job where you perform updates from smaller sets of nodes:

```
   MATCH (n:person)
   with n
   SKIP ${nodes-to-be-skipped} limit ${maximal-nodes-to-be-match-or-updated}
   SET n.name = NULL 
   RETURN n
```

If you know how many nodes are to be updated, you can know the % done.
Think that a bigger *limit* value, will need more memory, and a smaller one more commits (and therefore more time). So you can adapt it to your needs.

If you need some bulk operations you can take a look *bulk batch insertion* http://neo4j.com/docs/stable/batchinsert-examples.html which is must faster but works without transactions or indexing and therefore no consistency is checked.

It depends on your problem which can be a better solution. For what I can interpret for your post I would just run a job with paginated cypher queries.

Hope that helps.